Asking a question using ですか vs の
I see the following sentence in a language learning app: 背中が痛いの？ which it translated to Does your back hurt?
But from what I learnt so far, we can also say 背中が痛いですか？, no?
What's the difference between using ですか vs using の?

First things first: 「痛いの？」 is not the casual counterpart of 「痛いですか？」 but of 「痛いんですか？・痛いのですか？」
In polite speech, you use ですか or ますか, on the same rules as usual, to ask a question. Casually, however, you simply use the sentence, with a rising intonation at the end.
「痛いですか？」 is casually 「痛い？」
「痛いんですか・痛いのですか？」 is casually 「痛いの？」
As for the difference between the two, の, just like the のだ construction, seeks an explanation. The first asks neutrally. In the second, the speaker has some reason to believe the listener's back hurts; maybe they're stretching it a lot.

hmmm... so "背中が痛いのですか?" is kind of like "背中が痛いませんですか?" (i.e. "Doesn't your back hurt?")

@PieFaced No, it's different. You may not have studied the のです/んです "explanatory の" grammar point yet. The closest English translation would be "Is it that your back hurts?" but there's much more to the construction in Japanese. https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-no-desu-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-noda-meaning/

Oh just thought of checking something. Say we have a question like "which bag is it?" ("どの鞄ですか?"), and we want to answer with "the red one", which would be "赤いのです". The "の" in this case has a different "use" as the "の" in the original question, right?
